# ¿Como encadenar un método estático con una publico en PHP?

Tags: php

tengo esta api o crud, me funciona muy bien

```
<?php

namespace Core;

use Database\Conection;
use PDO;

class Api
{
    protected $data;
    protected $sql;
    protected $table;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = (new Conection())->on();
    }

    public function table($table = null)
    {
        if (isset($table)) {
            $this->table = $table;
            return $this;
        } else {
            echo "No existe la tabla";
        }
    }

    public function get()
    {
        $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM {$this->table}";
        $sentence = $this->db->prepare($this->sql);
        $sentence->execute();

        return $sentence->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
}
```

Al utilizarlo en mi index me va muy bien, me trae todos los datos de la bd no tengo ningun problema

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use Core\Api;

$DB = new Api();
$res = $DB->table('usuario')
    ->get();

var_dump($res);
```

Pero me urge la duda como podria utilizar el metodo table en estatico y llamar los otros metodos publicos, ya intente pero me sale error de no poder utilizar el $this dendro del metodo estatico table y nose si el encadenamiento de metodos funcione de esta manera, como podria generarlo

```
$res = $DB::table('usuario')->get();
```

De esta manera

Comment: ¿por qué quieres usar como estático a dicho método?

Comment: da como intuición que al usar DB debe ir el table (DB::table) y ya hay le siguen los otros métodos, pero no encuentro alguna manera de realizarlo.

Comment: No hace falta convertir el método en estático, sin embargo, lo que puedes hacer, es pasar la instancia de la clase `Api` al método `table`.

Comment: Lo que intentas lograr se parece mucho a Laravel. Quizá sea interesante que explores en su código fuente. La tabla se puede invocar así: `DB::table` [porque es declarada en la clase `DB` como una propiedad (cadena)  estática](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/DB.php#L9), **pero OJO a esto, la llamada `DB::table()` no es una llamada a un método `table` realmente** sino que es una llamada [al método `from()` de `Query/Builder`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Query/Builder.php#L425) el cual **no es estático**.

Comment: ya pude muchas gracias, tenia que retornar en vez de $this, retornar en nuevo estatico, return new static, y ya me queda asi $DB::table('usuario')->get();